# Using MIDI with Serial Midi Converter using usb to ttl converter

Tags: midi, electronics, audio

in market we have available usb to ttl converter. So can i use them to send midi signals to usb using
This circuit
https://irq5.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/midi-sch.png?w=640
connected to the pins of usb to ttl converter module

then using software "MIDI Yoke" and "serial to midi converter"

Please tell me if its possible because most of them do it by using the same pins on arduino uno r3

Answer (score 2):

That circuit is horribly wrong:

- The connections to pins 4 and 5 of the MIDI connector are exchanged (and that connector is labelled wrong).
- RB must be 220 Ω.
- The CNY17 optocoupler is often too slow; use a H11L1, or better a 6N137.
- RD is too large unless you're using a really fast optocoupler.

But when you're using a correct circuit (see, for example, [MIDI IN : many circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/165255/29811) or [MIDI to Arduino with a 4N38 Optocoupler](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/172144/29811)), this will work.

It might be a better idea to just buy a cheap USB/MIDI interface cable.